# Ok to use green Spax lags as anchors in block wall?

Tags: framing, concrete-block

I've got a basement project where I'm attaching 3in studs over 1 inch foam to a block wall (built ~1952). I was planning on using Tapcons, but the threads are not holding. The 1/4 green Spax lags look like they would do the trick, but my concern is - will they will rust out over time?